# C# generic collection to list

Tags: c#, list, generics

Let's say I have a class encapsulating a collection using an indexer, like this:

```
class MyCollection
{
    private List<int> internalCollection = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

    public int this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return internalCollection[i];
        }
        set
        {
            internalCollection[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to assign to a normal List variable, like this:

```
List<int> l = new List<int>(100);
MyCollection m = new MyCollection();
l = m;
```

I understand I am missing a cast, but I don't know how to make it correctly. How can I update the `MyCollection` type and what cast will I need so I can assign it to a `List<int>` variable?

Comment: Hard to say because you did not include the intent. Do you want to set the `internalCollection` on your `MyCollection` instance? Then add something like `public void SetCollection(List<int> list) { this.internalCollection = list; }` and then replace `l=m;` in the 2nd block of code with `m.SetCollection(l);`

Comment: The only way this would work is if `MyCollection` inherits from `List<int>`.  If you want to COPY the contents, you could do `.ToList()`, or if you really want to make your code convoluted and omit the `.ToList()` call you could implement an implicit cast https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators, where in the implicit cast operator you would copy the collection to a new `List<int>`.

Comment: You can [define your own operator for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) in the class, so the code as written will work. But typically when you find yourself wrapping a generic list you're making a mistake, and should instead use the bare List in the first place.

Comment: Also, the `new List<int>(100);` can **NEVER** have any meaning. If you define an object with the new operator, and then immediately assign a new value to the reference variable, that new allocation is **always** wasteful.

Comment: Must `l` be of type `List<int>` or would `IEnumerable<int>` or `ICollection<int>` be enough?